# Avoid for loop in string replacement?

Tags: r

I've got data, a character vector (eventually I'll collapse it, so I don't care if it stays a vector or if it's treated as a single string), a vector of patterns, and a vector of replacements. I want each pattern in the data to be replaced by its respective replacement. I got it done with a `stringr` and a for loop, but is there a more R-like way to do it?

```
require(stringr)
start_string <- sample(letters[1:10], 10)
my_pattern <- c("a", "b", "c", "z")
my_replacement <- c("[this was an a]", "[this was a b]", "[this was a c]", "[no z!]")
str_replace(start_string, pattern = my_pattern, replacement = my_replacement)
# bad lengths, doesn't work

str_replace(paste0(start_string, collapse = ""),
    pattern = my_pattern, replacement = my_replacement)
# vector output, not what I want in this case

my_result <- start_string
for (i in 1:length(my_pattern)) {
    my_result <- str_replace(my_result,
        pattern = my_pattern[i], replacement = my_replacement[i])
}
> my_result
 [1] "[this was a c]"  "[this was an a]" "e"               "g"               "h"               "[this was a b]" 
 [7] "d"               "j"               "f"               "i"   

# This is what I want, but is there a better way?
```

In my case, I know each pattern will occur at most once, but not every pattern will occur. I know I could use `str_replace_all` if patterns might occur more than once; I hope a solution would also provide that option. I'd also like a solution that uses `my_pattern` and `my_replacement` so that it could be part of a function with those vectors as arguments.

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop? They're perfect for this sort of situation where you're repeatedly modifying a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet there's another way to do this, but my first thought was **gsubfn**:

```
my_repl <- function(x){
    switch(x,a = "[this was an a]",
             b = "[this was a b]",
             c = "[this was a c]",
             z = "[this was a z]")
}

library(gsubfn)    
start_string <- sample(letters[1:10], 10)
gsubfn("a|b|c|z",my_repl,x = start_string)
```

If the patterns you are search for a acceptably valid names for list elements, this will also work:

```
names(my_replacement) <- my_pattern
gsubfn("a|b|c|z",as.list(my_replacement),start_string)
```

**Edit**

But frankly, if I really had to do this a lot in my own code, I would probably just do the `for` loop thing, wrapped in a function. Here's a simple version using `sub` and `gsub` rather than the functions from **stringr**:

```
vsub <- function(pattern,replacement,x,all = TRUE,...){
  FUN <- if (all) gsub else sub
  for (i in seq_len(min(length(pattern),length(replacement)))){
    x <- FUN(pattern = pattern[i],replacement = replacement[i],x,...)
  }
  x
}

vsub(my_pattern,my_replacement,start_string)
```

But of course, one of the reasons that there isn't a built-in function for this that's well known is probably that sequential replacements like this can't be pretty fragile, because they are so order dependent:

```
vsub(rev(my_pattern),rev(my_replacement),start_string)
 [1] "i"                                          "[this w[this was an a]s [this was an a] c]"
 [3] "[this was an a]"                            "g"                                         
 [5] "j"                                          "d"                                         
 [7] "f"                                          "[this w[this was an a]s [this was an a] b]"
 [9] "h"                                          "e"
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely avoids the loop (so satisfies all my mentioned criteria), but in the real case I've got enough patterns and replacements (nothing huge, just 15 or so) that I'd rather not write them all in a switch statement.

Comment: @shujaa There are other options, but only if the search strings are allowable as list item names (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option based on `gregrexpr`, `regmatches`, and `regmatches<-`. Do be aware that there are limits to the length of regular expressions that can be matched, so this won't work if you try to match too many long patterns with it.

```
replaceSubstrings <- function(patterns, replacements, X) {
    pat <- paste(patterns, collapse="|")
    m <- gregexpr(pat, X)
    regmatches(X, m) <- 
        lapply(regmatches(X,m),
               function(XX) replacements[match(XX, patterns)])
    X
}

## Try it out
patterns <- c("cat", "dog")
replacements <- c("tiger", "coyote")
sentences <- c("A cat", "Two dogs", "Raining cats and dogs")
replaceSubstrings(patterns, replacements, sentences)
## [1] "A tiger"                    "Two coyotes"               
## [3] "Raining tigers and coyotes"
```