# Replace words with r

Tags: r

I have words against their synonyms. In the different data frame, I have sentences. I want to search synonyms from the other dataframe. If found, replace it with word for which synomym found.

```
dt = read.table(header = TRUE, 
text ="Word Synonyms
Use 'employ, utilize, exhaust, spend, expend, consume, exercise'
Come    'advance, approach, arrive, near, reach'
Go  'depart, disappear, fade, move, proceed, recede, travel'
Run 'dash, escape, elope, flee, hasten, hurry, race, rush, speed, sprint'
Hurry   'rush, run, speed, race, hasten, urge, accelerate, bustle'
Hide    'conceal, cover, mask, cloak, camouflage, screen, shroud, veil'
", stringsAsFactors= F)

   mydf = read.table(header = TRUE, , stringsAsFactors= F,
                    text ="sentence
    'I can utilize this file'
    'I can cover these things'
    ")
```

The desired output looks like -

```
I can Use this file
I can Hide these things
```

Above is just a sample. In my real dataset, I have more than 10000 sentences. I am using the function below. It is slow. Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
dt$Synonyms <- paste("\\b",gsub(", ","\\\\b|\\\\b",tolower(dt$Synonyms)),"\\b", sep = "")

# Loop through each row of 'dt' to replace Synonyms with word using sapply
mydf$sentence <- sapply(tolower(mydf$sentence), function(x){
  for(row in 1:nrow(dt)){
    x = gsub(dt$Synonyms[row],dt$Word[row], x)
  }
  x
})

mydf
```

Comment: Using package stringi I suspect would improve performance.

Comment: Did some tests and couldn't improve your solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904588/avoid-for-loop-in-string-replacement

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

data:

```
dt = read.table(header = TRUE, 
                text ="Word Synonyms
Use 'employ, utilize, exhaust, spend, expend, consume, exercise'
Come    'advance, approach, arrive, near, reach'
Go  'depart, disappear, fade, move, proceed, recede, travel'
Run 'dash, escape, elope, flee, hasten, hurry, race, rush, speed, sprint'
Hurry   'rush, run, speed, race, hasten, urge, accelerate, bustle'
Hide    'conceal, cover, mask, cloak, camouflage, screen, shroud, veil'
", stringsAsFactors= F)

mydf = read.table(header = TRUE, , stringsAsFactors= F,
                  text ="sentence
    'I can utilize this file'
    'I can cover these things'
    'I can advance and cover also rush things'
    ")
```

code:

```
dt$Synonyms <- gsub(",\\s+","|",dt$Synonyms)

fun1 <- function(sentence){
    sentence <- sentence
    mapply(function(word,synon){sentence <<- gsub(synon, word, sentence)},word=dt$Word,synon=dt$Synonyms)
    return(sentence)
    }
mydf$sentence %>% lapply(fun1)
```

result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "I can Use this file"

[[2]]
[1] "I can Hide these things"

[[3]]
[1] "I can Come and Hide also Run things"
```

please note:

If you want to persist the changes to mydf replace `%>%` with `%<>%`.

```
mydf$sentence %<>% lapply(fun1)
```

Comment: I think benchmarking would be appropriate here since OP is looking for efficiency gains.